# How to theme Lightbox

Tags: drupal, lightbox, lightbox2

I need to theme my lightbox. I can see the HTML generated by the JavaScript code in lightbox.js, but I cannot overwrite that file, or I will lose my changes when I update the module. Is there any better way to override a theme output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't report for which Drupal version you are interested; the answer I am giving is valid for Drupal 6, but few things would change for Drupal 7.

Lightbox2 uses a [template file](http://drupalcode.org/project/lightbox2.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/page-node-lightbox2.tpl.php) for its output. If you create a custom module that implements [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/6) to use a different template file, then you can use a template file that uses a JavaScript file you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

can you not theme it just by changing the CSS?

In your theme's [**.info file**](http://drupal.org/node/231036) you can override the module's `css` and/or `js` and then you copy the css or js file from the module into your own theme folder, (every theme should have a .info, if not create one) - this means you don't touch the actual contrib modules files

Drupal will then use the one from your theme, which you can edit to your hearts content, and if you do hit problems you just remove the entry from the .info file and it will then go back to using the original module filea.

I haven't done it for JS but I believe the process is the same as for CSS and here is a snippet of what's in my .info file - btw I think once you use this method of overriding you have to declare the default style.css  too

```
stylesheets[all][] = style.css
stylesheets[all][] = lightbox.css
```

### Update:

It's only possible to use the .info file to override JS in D7, but there is module [JSAlter](http://drupal.org/project/jsalter) which might help with D6

Comment: The theming I need to do means I cant just override the CSS. I need to actually change the html the js creates. As this is part of the lightbox module I dont think I can do this by loading different js. Thanks

Comment: I think you can override your JS in the same way, via the .info file.. then you could rewrite it inside your theme without a module update affecting it

Comment: sorry I misinformed you, it's only possible to treat JS this way in D7, however there's a module [JSAlter](http://drupal.org/project/jsalter) which does it D6

Comment: Ok, maybe I could 'hijack' the js file. It wont necessarily be update proof as an update could change the original js file, and then maybe my override wont work with the module anymore. Unless theirs another way I think for simplicity ill just stick with my hacky method and hope the lightbox module isn't updated too often. Thanks